# Need to get Name, Node Name and Phase Values from API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get Name, Node Name and Phase values from JSON Data using JavaScript. Here is my JavaScript

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('http://ec2-3-82-117-70.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/api/v0/retrievePodStatus/default',
            function (data) {
              console.log(data)

             document.body.append("Name: " + data.items[1].metadata.name);
                // document.body.append(data.items[1].metadata.name);
                // document.body.append(data.items[0].spec.nodeName);
            });
    });


</script>
```

I am just getting the name in here. Can someone please help me how to get Name, Node Name and Phase Values? find the below JSON as well.

```
"apiVersion": "v1",
"items": [
    {
        "apiVersion": "v1",
        "kind": "Pod",
        "metadata": {
            "annotations": {
                "kubernetes.io/limit-ranger": "LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container external-dns"
            },
            "creationTimestamp": "2019-02-28T16:22:49Z",
            "generateName": "external-dns-5d69b66646-",
            "labels": {
                "app": "external-dns",
                "pod-template-hash": "1825622202"
            },
            "name": "external-dns-5d69b66646-pmxmd",
            "namespace": "default",
            "ownerReferences": [
                {
                    "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
                    "blockOwnerDeletion": true,
                    "controller": true,
                    "kind": "ReplicaSet",
                    "name": "external-dns-5d69b66646",
                    "uid": "170d9260-3b75-11e9-abe2-0ec5819342ce"
                }
            ],
            "resourceVersion": "2984",
            "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/external-dns-5d69b66646-pmxmd",
            "uid": "170e1a0d-3b75-11e9-abe2-0ec5819342ce"
        },
        "spec": {
            "containers": [
                {
                    "args": [
                        "--source=service",
                        "--source=ingress",
                        "--provider=aws",
                        "--registry=txt",
                        "--txt-owner-id=qpair"
                    ],
                    "image": "registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns:v0.4.2",
                    "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
                    "name": "external-dns",
                    "resources": {
                        "requests": {
                            "cpu": "100m"
                        }
                    },
                    "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
                    "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
                    "volumeMounts": [
                        {
                            "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount",
                            "name": "default-token-rr546",
                            "readOnly": true
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
            "nodeName": "ip-172-20-39-147.ec2.internal",
            "restartPolicy": "Always",
            "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
            "securityContext": {},
            "serviceAccount": "default",
            "serviceAccountName": "default",
            "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
            "tolerations": [
                {
                    "effect": "NoExecute",
                    "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
                    "operator": "Exists",
                    "tolerationSeconds": 300
                },
                {
                    "effect": "NoExecute",
                    "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
                    "operator": "Exists",
                    "tolerationSeconds": 300
                }
            ],
            "volumes": [
                {
                    "name": "default-token-rr546",
                    "secret": {
                        "defaultMode": 420,
                        "secretName": "default-token-rr546"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "status": {
            "conditions": [
                {
                    "lastProbeTime": null,
                    "lastTransitionTime": "2019-02-28T16:22:49Z",
                    "status": "True",
                    "type": "Initialized"
                },
                {
                    "lastProbeTime": null,
                    "lastTransitionTime": "2019-02-28T16:22:58Z",
                    "status": "True",
                    "type": "Ready"
                },
                {
                    "lastProbeTime": null,
                    "lastTransitionTime": "2019-02-28T16:22:49Z",
                    "status": "True",
                    "type": "PodScheduled"
                }
            ],
            "containerStatuses": [
                {
                    "containerID": "docker://18b96317cf360d562fb3f849c6716c50a41a67a4dbc126164020531e1e4d84a9",
                    "image": "registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns:v0.4.2",
                    "imageID": "docker-pullable://registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns@sha256:d54b9eb8948b87eb7fcd938990ff2dbc9ca0a42d9c5d36fcaa75c7cf066f7995",
                    "lastState": {},
                    "name": "external-dns",
                    "ready": true,
                    "restartCount": 0,
                    "state": {
                        "running": {
                            "startedAt": "2019-02-28T16:22:57Z"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "hostIP": "172.20.39.147",
            "phase": "Running",
            "podIP": "100.96.7.3",
            "qosClass": "Burstable",
            "startTime": "2019-02-28T16:22:49Z"
        }
    },
```

I am just getting the name in here. Can someone please help me how to get Name, Node Name and Phase Values? find the below JSON as well.

Thanks, Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You were close with the code you posted. You just needed `items[0]` instead of `items[1]`. Remember the first element of an array is always 0. Other than that its as easy as checking the open and close brackets `[]` or `{}` to see where each nested object/array starts and ends.

Code:

```
var name = data.items[0].metadata.name
var nodeName = data.items[0].spec.nodeName
var phase = data.items[0].status.phase
```

snippet:

```js
var data = {
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "items": [{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "Pod",
    "metadata": {
      "annotations": {
        "kubernetes.io/limit-ranger": "LimitRanger plugin set: cpu request for container external-dns"
      },
      "creationTimestamp": "2019-02-28T16:22:49Z",
      "generateName": "external-dns-5d69b66646-",
      "labels": {
        "app": "external-dns",
        "pod-template-hash": "1825622202"
      },
      "name": "external-dns-5d69b66646-pmxmd",
      "namespace": "default",
      "ownerReferences": [{
        "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
        "blockOwnerDeletion": true,
        "controller": true,
        "kind": "ReplicaSet",
        "name": "external-dns-5d69b66646",
        "uid": "170d9260-3b75-11e9-abe2-0ec5819342ce"
      }],
      "resourceVersion": "2984",
      "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/external-dns-5d69b66646-pmxmd",
      "uid": "170e1a0d-3b75-11e9-abe2-0ec5819342ce"
    },
    "spec": {
      "containers": [{
        "args": [
          "--source=service",
          "--source=ingress",
          "--provider=aws",
          "--registry=txt",
          "--txt-owner-id=qpair"
        ],
        "image": "registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns:v0.4.2",
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
        "name": "external-dns",
        "resources": {
          "requests": {
            "cpu": "100m"
          }
        },
        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
        "volumeMounts": [{
          "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount",
          "name": "default-token-rr546",
          "readOnly": true
        }]
      }],
      "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
      "nodeName": "ip-172-20-39-147.ec2.internal",
      "restartPolicy": "Always",
      "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
      "securityContext": {},
      "serviceAccount": "default",
      "serviceAccountName": "default",
      "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
      "tolerations": [{
          "effect": "NoExecute",
          "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
          "operator": "Exists",
          "tolerationSeconds": 300
        },
        {
          "effect": "NoExecute",
          "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
          "operator": "Exists",
          "tolerationSeconds": 300
        }
      ],
      "volumes": [{
        "name": "default-token-rr546",
        "secret": {
          "defaultMode": 420,
          "secretName": "default-token-rr546"
        }
      }]
    },
    "status": {
      "conditions": [{
          "lastProbeTime": null,
          "lastTransitionTime": "2019-02-28T16:22:49Z",
          "status": "True",
          "type": "Initialized"
        },
        {
          "lastProbeTime": null,
          "lastTransitionTime": "2019-02-28T16:22:58Z",
          "status": "True",
          "type": "Ready"
        },
        {
          "lastProbeTime": null,
          "lastTransitionTime": "2019-02-28T16:22:49Z",
          "status": "True",
          "type": "PodScheduled"
        }
      ],
      "containerStatuses": [{
        "containerID": "docker://18b96317cf360d562fb3f849c6716c50a41a67a4dbc126164020531e1e4d84a9",
        "image": "registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns:v0.4.2",
        "imageID": "docker-pullable://registry.opensource.zalan.do/teapot/external-dns@sha256:d54b9eb8948b87eb7fcd938990ff2dbc9ca0a42d9c5d36fcaa75c7cf066f7995",
        "lastState": {},
        "name": "external-dns",
        "ready": true,
        "restartCount": 0,
        "state": {
          "running": {
            "startedAt": "2019-02-28T16:22:57Z"
          }
        }
      }],
      "hostIP": "172.20.39.147",
      "phase": "Running",
      "podIP": "100.96.7.3",
      "qosClass": "Burstable",
      "startTime": "2019-02-28T16:22:49Z"
    }
  }],

}

var name = data.items[0].metadata.name
var nodeName = data.items[0].spec.nodeName
var phase = data.items[0].status.phase
console.log(name)
console.log(nodeName)
console.log(phase)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the solution. How do I get the array values from this JSON by looping?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking. Which array are you trying to loop through? Most of the nested arrays only have one element, which is a huge nested object. This is pretty standard for returned json objects so there usually isnt a need for looping. If you wanted to loop through something like the tolerations array (which has two elements, both nested objects) you can do something like `for (var i = 0; i < data.items[0].spec.tolerations.length; i++){
  console.log(data.items[0].spec.tolerations[i])
}` and it will give you each object under tolerations. Otherwise could you clarify?